# AVPlayer video freezed when interactive pop gesture

Tags: ios, video

I wrote my sample code of AVPlayer for video playback. According to Apple docs initial the video player:

```
- (AVPlayer *)player {
    if (!_player) {
        AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kVideoURL] options:nil];
        AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
        [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
        [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"loadedTimeRanges" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
        _player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    }
    return _player;
}
```

**Problem:**
When I tried to pop the viewController by interactive gesture, the video frame stalled even freezed sometime. [Here is the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRABw.jpg)

Could any one help me ? THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: Hi~ ,have you resolve it ? I came across the same problem!

Comment: It seems like Apple's issue, I solved it by use custom interactive gesture. Also you can pause the video when viewcontroller disappear and resume after pop gesture canceled.